# Make a ragged list rectangular by trimming instead of padding

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a ragged list

```
ragged = {{a,b,c,d,e},{x,y,z}}
```

that I would like to trim (on the right) to be rectangular. The desired result is

```
{{a,b,c},{x,y,z}}
```

It seems like this should be a one-word operation but I can't find the one word. So far the best I can do is to PadRight with Null and then delete everything with a Null in it.

```
Transpose[
 DeleteCases[
  Transpose[
   PadRight[
    ragged,
    Automatic,
    Null
    ]
   ],
  a_ /; MemberQ[a, Null]
  ]
 ]
```

This seems way too complicated for such a simple operation. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Take.html). To then make the array rectangular, I would do something like this

```
Take[ragged, All, Min[Length /@ ragged] ]
```

Comment: How did he fix that without it showing the edit?

Comment: @BrettChampion I was within the 5 minute window.

Answer (score 14):

What about:

```
ragged[[All, 1 ;; Min[Length /@ ragged]]]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}

Comment: Very nice ! You can even drop `1` and write `ragged[[All, ;; Min[Length /@ ragged]]]`

Comment: Yep! Good for the [oneliner contest](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/01/the-2011-mathematica-one-liner-competition/) but potentially dangerous for sloppy readers (i.e. me).

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like

```
PadRight[ragged, {Automatic, Min[Length /@ ragged]}]
```

Comment: `Automatic` apparently doesn't work on v7.

Comment: +1 for showing that `PadRight` can remove elements. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a timing comparison of the methods presented.  I had to modify Heike's code because it did not work on version 7.

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

ragged = RandomReal[99, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{25, 100}, 5000];

PadRight[ragged, {Length@ragged, Min[Length /@ ragged]}]; // timeAvg

ragged[[All, ;; Min[Length /@ ragged]]]; // timeAvg

Take[ragged, All, Min[Length /@ ragged]]; // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.02808
>
> 0.002864
>
> 0.002744
> ```

```
ragged = RandomReal[99, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{2500, 5000}, 50];

PadRight[ragged, {Length@ragged, Min[Length /@ ragged]}]; // timeAvg

ragged[[All, ;; Min[Length /@ ragged]]]; // timeAvg

Take[ragged, All, Min[Length /@ ragged]]; // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.01688
>
> 0.00009184
>
> 0.000088896
> ```

rcollyer wins!

Comment: I modified my answer to what you proposed when I was fixed the "Trim" issue.

Comment: Darn. You win again, Mr. Wizard (or  rcollyer, I a afraid of a grandfather paradox).

Comment: @rcollyer corrected

Comment: @YvesKlett rcollyer beat me to it :-)

Comment: I was also looking at `Drop`, but I don't think it can be done without some serious convolutions.

Comment: @YvesKlett well, we've already established that I'm part of the Mr.Wizard [collective](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156/52).

Comment: Great. Now I´ll have to spend the rest of the day to search for some far-fetched example to demonstrate `Part`s superiority. S´ not like I have a job or something. No [borg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_%28Star_Trek%29), me!

Comment: @YvesKlett just plug your brain directly into the computer. It makes multi-tasking so much easier and addictive.

Answer (score 3):

In version 10 the package GeneralUtilites contains the functions `TrimLeft` and `TrimRight`:

```
x = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}};

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

TrimLeft[x]
TrimRight[x]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}}
>
> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}
> ```

Burdened with the additional argument testing overhead of a packaged function these are not quite as fast as the raw methods posted earlier but they are sufficient.  The core of each is akin to Yves Klett's answer:

```
lists[[All, -Min[Length /@ lists] ;; All]]

lists[[All, 1 ;; Min[Length /@ lists]]]
```