# Problem in plotting complex valued data in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I have a situation where a function `sys` yields solutions in complex values while I change its argument `x from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$ as in the following:

```
Bands[sys[t1, t2, 3], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

which gives me list of complex values with `x` as following:

```
{{-3.14159, -1.99705 + 0.0000290634 I}, {-3.02073, -1.99703 - 
0.0000293392 I}, {-2.8897, -1.99698 - 
0.0000302499 I}, {-2.76735, -1.99691 - 0.0000316411 I},...{3.14159, 1.99705 
+0.0000290634 I}}
```

Now if I write

```
Re[Bands[sys[t1, t2, 3], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]
```

it gives me correct list of real parts of the complex values which is:

> {{-3.14159, -1.99705},{-3.02073, -1.99703},{-2.8897, -1.99698}...so on} 
>   but for imaginary parts:

```
Im[Bands[sys[t1, t2, 3], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]
```

it gives me:

> {{0,0.0000290634 I},{0,- 0.0000293392 I},{0,- 0.0000302499 I}...so on}

thus, not showing the correct values of variable `x`. As a result, the real values giving me correct plot but the imaginary values don't give me correct plot since the values of 'x' show all zero which is not true.

Someone (@Rom38) suggested me to use: `{First@#, Im@Last@#} & /@ [Bands[...]`. But in my case how do I implement it when the plot command I use to plot the imaginary part is:

```
PlotBands[Im[Bands[sys[t1, t2, 1.5], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2[Pi]}]], FrameLabel -> {"x", "Im(E)"}]
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: It is clear that imaginary part of the real number is zero.
Try something like `{First@#,Im@Last@#}&/@Bands[....]`

Comment: Actually my problem is precisely as in this link:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58549/listplot-imaginary-part-of-complex-numbers?rq=1
@ Rom38 I couldn't understand your point. Can you explain.

Comment: My point is following: applying the `Im` for both `{x,y}`, you will have `{0,Im[y]}` in case if `x` is already real. Mapping my pure function `{First@#,Im@Last@#}&` for each sublist of your list, you will apply the `Im` only to second element of each `{x,y}` pair. You should use the `/@` command for this. As result, just copy-paste my code from previous comment  and see the result

Comment: @Sam don't use answers to comment. Even with low reputation you can comment under your questions. The problem seems to be that you have created two accounts, see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to fix this.